# Substring replacement using str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I am just trying to get my head round str_replace and curly brackets / braces .
With the following line, I know that typing {the_title} will get replaces with the array $some_runtime_generated_title , but what does the first value mean ($str_template) ?.

```
str_replace( $str_template, '{the_title}', $some_runtime_generated_title );
```

Say I wanted to do the following........

```
$dog='lassy';
{dog}
would output >> lassy
```

How would I do that in php ?

Comment: Are you looking for a template engine (in the spirit of MustacheJS) for PHP?

Comment: This kind of question is easily answered with [a quick grasp at the manual](http://php.net/str_replace). It even has examples. I can't understand how people manages to code without the manual.

Comment: I read the manual before I came here, but I didn't understand it, reading something and understanding them are totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple use case of str_replace for place holder replacement would look like:

```
$paramNames = array("{name}", "{year}", "{salutation}");
$paramValues = array("Iain Simpson", "2012", "Alloha");
$text = "{salutation}, {name}! Happy {year}!";
str_replace($paramNames, $paramValues, $text);
```

`$paramNames` and `$paramValues` arrays have same number of values.

A more specific purpose function would be:

```
/* Processes a text template by replacing {param}'s with corresponding values. A variation fo this function could accept a name of a file containing the template text. */
/* Parameters: */
/*   template - a template text */
/*   params   - an assoc array (or map) of template parameter name=>value pairs */
function process_template($template, $params) {
    $result = $template;
    foreach ($params as $name => $value) {
        // echo "Replacing {$name} with '$value'"; // echo can be used for debugging purposes
        $result = str_replace("{$name}", $value, $result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
$text = process_template("{salutation}, {name}! Happy {year}!", array(
    "name" => "Iain", "year" => 2012, "salutation" => "Alloha"
));
```

Here's an example of an object-oriented approach:

```
class TextTemplate {
   private static $left = "{";
   private static $right = "}";
   private $template;

   function __construct($template) {
       $this->template = $template;
   }

   public function apply($params) {
       $placeholders = array();
       $values = array();
       foreach($params as $name => $value) {
           array_push($placeholders, self::$left . $name . self::$right);
           array_push($values, $value);
       }
       $result = str_replace($placeholders, $values, $this->template);
       return $result;
   }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$template = new TextTemplate("{salutation}, {name}! Happy {year}!");
$text = $template->apply(array("name" => "Iain", "year" => 2012, "salutation" => "Alloha"));
```

Comment: Ahh that makes more, sense, thanks for your help, I will have a play around with it in a moment and see what I can do, it looks quite useful for email templates and things, but I only read about it for the first time yesterday and most explanations where confusing.

Comment: How do I get the replacement to echo out ?, I have tried echo '{name}'; but that just gives me {name}, I also tried just {name} but this gives me a php error.

Comment: @Iain, Am not sure what you want to achieve, but a simple echo of a variable can be done as `echo "{$name}";`.

Answer (score 1):

You practically gave the answer yourself:

```
<?php
$some_runtime_generated_title = 'generated title';
$str_template = 'This is the template in which you use {the_title}';
$parsed = str_replace( '{the_title}', $some_runtime_generated_title, $str_template );
echo $parsed;
```

Comment: I guess, `$str_template` should be the last parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I copied that code off another post, I didnt write it myself, it was just an example. Does that mean that $str_template is just an array ?. so the first part is an array of values, the second part is the 'keyword' you want to be replaced and the third bit is the value that you want it replaced with ?, how does that tie into the first array ?, is the last array part of the first ?.

Comment: so like : $names {nameis} $nameis='frank' would echo frank ?

Comment: You should read str_replace as:
str_replace($keywords, $with_values, $in_string)

Comment: @IainSimpson @Vlad My bad, I left the parameters mixed up. It should be `str_replace( $search, $replace, $subject )`. I fixed it in the example. @Iain `$str_template` is just the "whole" text which *contains* the words that have to be replaced.