# Using curly braces in an email / article to insert the customers name

Tags: php, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I have looked and looked for an example on this, but the only ones I have found are echoing the result of the str replace like this :

```
$malestr = str_replace("{name}", "$name", $rawstring);
echo "$malestr";
```

But this is not what I want, what I am trying to do is....... when I create a template, in the text box field for the message I would write :

Dear {name},
Thankyou for your order !.

Name being the person I am writing too, that is pulled from the $toPersonsName array when the email is sent :

So the result of this would be in the email as follows :

If the customer was called bob, it would be >>

Dear Bob,
Thankyou for your order !.

Is this str_replace I need for this or is it something else, as I don't want to have to write

```
Dear <?php echo '$malestr';?>
```

every time I create a template, {name} would be better.

EDIT >>

If I do the following :

```
$name = 'BOB';
$rawstring = "$name";

$malestr = str_replace("{name}", "$name", $rawstring);


echo "$malestr";
echo "{name}";
```

It echos {name} , but not bob ??, yet $malestr echo's bob, how can I get {name} to echo bob ?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you already have? What is the issue with using the value stored in the variable?

Comment: if I echo 'Dear {name}, Thankyou for your order!.' I just get {name}, it doesnt replace it with the name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substring replacement using str_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710376/substring-replacement-using-str-replace)

Comment: @IainSimpson don't ask the same question again even if you don't get an answer. Instead, improve your original question. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods of string replacement and you can see in [this blog post](http://blogs.simplemachines.org/dev/175031/PHP+String+Replacement+Speed+Comparison.html) how they compare as far as speed.

Ultimately you need to parse your entire view output (if you are using MVC) and replace each instance. The popular template engine, [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net), uses something very similar to what you are trying to achieve. It is open source if you would like to look at how they accomplish this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtr() native function to do this.

Comment: How would I replace {name} using this ?